# How can I mount remote folder on D-Link 320 automatic?

Tags: mount, fstab, remote, nas

I have a D-link 320 NAS server with my movies and musics on there.

How can I mount it automatic on login?

I´m using Ubuntu 12.04 on Ultrabook Samsung Series 5.

The path for my data is:

//192.168.254.7/Volume_1/Musicas
//192.168.254.7/Volume_1/Filmes

How would the exact line I have to add to fstab look like?

Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 1):

You should install cifs-utils: sudo apt-get install cifs-utils

Create a Directory inside your home folder: sudo mkdir /media/Musicas

Edit fstab file with sudo nano /etc/fstab and add the following line at the end

```
//192.168.254.7/Volume_1/Musicas  /media/Musicas  cifs guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode  0  0
```

After editing the file do a sudo mount -a, that should make it work.

Comment: Hey man, thanx for yout attention, but I did everything like you said and I got this error:

$ sudo mount -a
mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

What I did wrong?

Comment: Try modify the line to: //192.168.254.7/Volume_1/Musicas /media/Musicas cifs guest,users,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode 0 0 Please note that i added the "users"

Comment: Hey man, thanx for your help.

I did this way and this is the only way i can mount:

//192.168.254.7/Volume_1/Musicas  /media/Musicas  cifs users,uid=1000  0  0

Comment: So i guess it worked?, is it mounting on reboot?

Comment: Yeah man, it´s working! Really thanx for your help!

Comment: Glad it helped. It will be good if you mark this question as answered also, so other people can benefit out of it.